# Power Automate - Condition result is always true

Tags: power-automate

My flow checks if there is a file in a folder. If there is, it appends a string to the filename to avoid duplicate file names. It then copies the file to another folder and deletes it.
The problem is, the majority of the time there are no files in the folder. When this happens, the flow fails. I am trying to resolve this with a conditional statement. The statement I am using must not be correct since even when there are no files in my folder, it is returning true.

[image: My flow]

[image: Run Results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Condition` step it's checking `Body` is not null, which it isn't, it's just an empty array (again it's not null even if it's empty), to check for an empty body (which is an empty array) this should be the condition expression:

`empty(outputs('List_files_in_folder')?['body']) is equal to true`

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!